# How to load a nib?

Tags: objective-c, macos, interface-builder, xcode4.2

I have a nib named, myNib, and it's owner is a custom NSWindowController subclass. All I want to do is to load it and put it into view so I can use it.

I tried assigning an outlet of a my window and passing it to the "initWithWindow" method of my NSWindowController, but it didn't work and I still don't see anything, just the default MainMenu.xib.

I feel like this is very simple, but I've been trying for hours just to get my xib into view so I can use it.

Comment: Did you write the NIB and custom `NSWindowController` subclass, or is it something you found on the internet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the `initWithWindowNibName` message -- it does exactly this.

You could also try using

```
NSNib * nibFile =  [[NSNib alloc] initWithNibNamed:@"myNib" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
```

to get the nib file yourself, and then yank the required window contents from there, but that's probably an overkill for what you're trying to do.